# What is the fastest elementary proof of $A_n≥G_n$?

Tags: alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The $A_m≥G_m$ has a whole lot of proofs, the large majority I've seen by induction. Currently the quickest one that I've seen is the following: (note $A_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n}{n}, G_n=\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}$ where $a_k$ is a positive real number).

Consider the geometric series: $1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+(1+x)^3+...+(1+x)^{n-1}=\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}$ for all integers $n≥0$.

If $x≥0$ then clearly $1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+(1+x)^3+...+(1+x)^{n-1}≥n$ which we then substitute into the expression to get $(1+x)^n≥1+nx$, if $-1≤x<0$ then $1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+(1+x)^3+...+(1+x)^{n-1}≤n$ which then substitutes re-arranges to $(1+x)^n≥1+nx$ again, noting that the sign flips when the $x$ in the denominator is multiplied across because it is assumed to be negative.

Hence we have shown $(1+x)^n≥1+nx$ is true for $x≥-1$. Then for $n=n+1$ substitute $x=\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_{n}}-1$ to derive the result $\left(\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_{n}}\right)^{n+1}≥\frac{a_{n+1}}{A_n}$.

The proof then finishes with induction with the assumption being $A_k≥G_k$ the the $k+1$ step being:

$LHS=G_{k+1}$
$=\sqrt[k+1]{a_1a_2a_3...a_{k+1}}$
$=(\sqrt[k]{a_1a_2a_3...a_{k}})^{\frac{k}{k+1}}\sqrt[k+1]{a_{k+1}}$
$≤(A_k)^{\frac{k}{k+1}}\sqrt[k+1]{a_{k+1}}$ by assumption
$≤\left(\sqrt[k]{\frac{A_{k+1}^{k+1}}{a_{k+1}}}\right)^{\frac{k}{k+1}}\sqrt[k+1]{a_{k+1}}$ using the proved inequality rearranged for $A_k$
$=A_{k+1}$ which completes the proof.

I was wondering what is the absolute quickest way (the least amount of steps that can still be followed without any extra work between those steps) that I can prove $A_n≥G_n$ from the ground up (maybe without induction)? That is, not using any other inequality results without proof, (this proof used Bernoulli's inequality but that was relatively quick to prove) and not using any advanced techniques (to me) such as matrices or something.

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "fastest".

Comment: @markvs A proof requiring the least amount of steps that can still be followed without any extra work between those steps.

Comment: "can still be followed without any extra work between those steps." is even more subjective. Can be followed by whom?

Comment: @markvs A high-school student with a reasonable amount of exposure to maths, enough to want to ask this question out of curiosity

Comment: You seem to be unable to formulate precisely. What is "reasonable amount of exposure"? I learned this formula and a proof when I was 14. I was in a middle school. There were more than 25 students in my class and there were millions of students    in my country who learned it at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln$ is concave then :
$$\ln \dfrac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \geq \dfrac{\ln a_1 + \cdots + \ln a_n}{n} = \ln \sqrt[n]{a_1 \cdots a_n}$$
And we are done.